# How to create a view where data resides in a view on remote Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure-sql-database, external-data-source

I'm trying to create a view of data that resides in remote Azure SQL Server.  I can't seem to create a table or temp table in the view to store the results of the sp_exeucte_remote call because that is not allowed so I tried to use a function, but then I get an error complaining about the following error based on the provided function definition.

`Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT EXEC' within a function`

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Test]()
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    [ID] INT,
    [$ShardName] VARCHAR(500)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Results
    EXEC sp_execute_remote N'MyExternalDatasource', N'SELECT 1' 
    RETURN;
END
```

How can one create a view of data that exists on a remote Azure SQL Server where that data also exists as a view?  FYI - the server where I'm trying to create the view is also Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a FUNCTION?

As per [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15) you cannot call a Stored Procedure within a function.

Also, your remote execution is only returning 1 column and you haven't defined the destination column to insert to.

The fact that the remote object is a VIEW does not matter.  If we assume that the VIEW on the remote database has columns also named ID and [$shardname] then why not just use something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #results ([ID] int, [$shardname] varchar(500))
INSERT #results ([ID], [$shardname])
EXEC sp_execute_remote N'ExternalSource', N'SELECT [ID], [$shardname] FROM RemoteTableName'
```

Comment: I started using the function because I was unable to create temp or table variables in a view that would be necessary to return results back from a stored procedure.  So then I tried the function knowing I could at least create variables and stuff, but then ran across the stored procedure point you mentioned.  That's where I kind up threw my hands up and posted this in stack.  I was trying to make the example simple, but may have made it more confusing.  The real question I'm trying to get help with is how would you access a view on a remote Azure SQL Server?

Comment: I just realized something...I can create an EXTERNAL TABLE on a VIEW.  Should have tried that.

Comment: Also, a Stored Procedure can return results without a View - it is simply the final SELECT  statement in the Stored Procedure.    INSERT INTO ... EXEC proc   is a valid construct